# apt error message ubuntu virtualbox guest

Tags: apt, 20.04, virtualbox, guest-os

So i have just installed Ubuntu (Minumal Installation) on Virtual Box Mac. I cant install any software form apt. It gives me error saying

```
E: Unable to locate package cmatrix
```

i have had this problem before and fixed it by somehow updating snapd (I deleted the vm). Now when i try to do that it gives me an error. then it goes away. But nothing channged. I have also tried `sudo apt update` but it fails

```
E: some index files failed to download
```

**Edit:**
i tried the [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)
and it did nothing

heres the new full error message

note: i made this change before but it seemed to not have saved because it was back to `nz.archive.ubuntu.com`

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/restricted/source/by-hash/SHA256/e4c92ef2e003ed3264e76c7df048b5b635c595c5ce10680b3f89761a01695ff1  File has unexpected size (13183 != 6472). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:6472 [weak]
    - SHA256:e4c92ef2e003ed3264e76c7df048b5b635c595c5ce10680b3f89761a01695ff1
    - SHA1:57fab19d8cee8a3feaf7c84420350094f9937785 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:55c93c10aa16a7e26010fa7bd55c7294 [weak]
   Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/a00e79d71544f34be89543e090ccafce943577e1a1b997780c07bb75766750b3  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/7c5810c7adbacd42400848d09af06dad52ce4597b16f9e7fa36141375f40da24  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/52805f5b7237153f9b4173b0bfe51917175eff5ca0f9feeb6d4dfcdd88918f70  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/b8a6c70d793758b8e231f5b901156049aa562872fd9df0a807ca3c9df6556d16  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/ba4c9cf04162b981885818b1e3b415f841680ff60c1e647adbdd545ab1e7d17b  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/restricted/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/cd98f05f351d05500deef4311554710cf9bc1c39a61f198bd4733cafc9a38c98  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/b504fbe86bb3a8ade20fcffcfc9036c732ab5f198c40d5a6a5a5685d20058966  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/233757b7df68e16c18ccad612ff13a8bb68fc36ac6d35f13427cafd70d8b5d42  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/224cafd684a26e8bce3dfca4daf33b853c9273d13e4ada6161ce9ef38f1a567c  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/d3eb7ca9f47c55f0031d59664a1b53f03ce3461ad565e3e568e00ff5a41f4fc3  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: We can't read the error messages except those you provided; the "*some index files failed to download*" is a summary with the purpose of getting you to read earlier messages that contain errors.  As you didn't provide the actual errors (only summary), we can currently only tell you to read the error messages (and provide them if you'd like help from us).   The package `cmatrix` (`cmatrix | 2.0-2        | focal/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`) is in 'universe' so did you enable it?

Comment: @guiverc i just installed a fresh vm it should be on by default. but the universe repo not bieng enbaled shouldn't cause the ```sudo apt update``` to fail

Comment: You'll have to read the error messages, as you've provided only the final summary (that informs you to read further up the listing for the actual error message) I cannot provide any clue as I can only read messages you posted (and you gave only final summary details, not the actual error messages)

Comment: i fixed it now.

Comment: You're using the Free Software Mirror Group **mirror**, (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) the clue was the *sync in progress?* message, so either try again later OR use a Ubuntu/Canonical site instead of mirror.

Comment: i am sorry what do you mean (i am new to ubuntu)

Comment: Key is `http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` is not a Ubuntu archive, you're using a mirror (ping the address and you'll note see where the reply is from.... this is general networking detail and not Ubuntu specific).  From that detail I looked up the site I provided (list of mirrors) and got the name in my prior comment.. By removing the "nz." you'll use a Canonical/Ubuntu site (instead of [country] mirror) which can be done by editor, package management tool etc...  minimal means usually `vi` or like text editor is easiest.  The only Ubuntu specific detail was the mirror list link I provided

Comment: so do i edit the sources.list file and remove nz?

Comment: Have you tried again?   If it was a `sync` error as the message suggested, usually it's gone in a few mins to few hours anyway (depending on mirror being used & their policies).. but yeah removing "nz." would switch you to a Canonical/Ubuntu archive site (instead of country mirror which was hosted by Free Software Mirror Group as I read the URL I provided

Comment: i did but the same error happended

Comment: @guiverc i need help with this i tried but the same error happended

Comment: I don't know the mirror you're  using (*Research and Education Advanced Network New Zealand* is owner doesn't stand out on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors but I said it was the FSMG earlier) so as per my last three comments I'd remove the country (`nz.`) detail & use the main archive instead of whomever you are using. I'd use an editor as I said two comments back, but you can use GUI tools too if using a desktop system.

Comment: i told you thats what i did i removed nz. in sources list

Comment: I'd suggest adjusting your question then with the newer detail.. as it still shows you using http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/  (ie. updating it & replacing the old detail with where you are now.. you want help with your current issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED IT i was sooo stupid. so i was unable to access the website for reasons then i fixed it and BOOM

I am sooo sorry for the inconvenience